# Rating Progress chart with 5 progress bar

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to draw a rating chart for my reviews on app. separatly for every star like 1,2,3,4, and 5. for reference i uploaded a image please suggest me n=best way.[image]

Comment: what have you tried? post your code with specific problem or it is very broad to answer.

Comment: So you want to give rating Similar to Play Store

Comment: @Ashish yes, same as play store

Comment: @DavinderGoel he already gave you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You can do something like below like taking 5 RatingBar and 5 ProgressBar.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="10dp">
>
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rating_5"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:numStars="5"
>         android:rating="5" />
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progress_5"
>         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:progress="50" />
>
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rating_4"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:numStars="4"
>         android:rating="4" />
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progress_4"
>         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:progress="50" />
>
>
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rating_3"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_4"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:numStars="3"
>         android:rating="3" />
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progress_3"
>         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_4"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:progress="30" />
>
>
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rating_2"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_3"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:numStars="2"
>         android:rating="2" />
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progress_2"
>         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_3"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:progress="20" />
>
>
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rating_1"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_2"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:numStars="1"
>         android:rating="1" />
>
>     <ProgressBar
>         android:id="@+id/progress_1"
>         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/rating_2"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_5"
>         android:progress="10" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Here is the output:

[image: Rating Image]

Hope it will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your response. it's that what acutely i'm doing. but it's hard to manage rating separatly. can we make it more easier to it.

Comment: We can use ListView . and put the rows into it. In this case we only need one RatingBar and one ProgressBar.